# Expectation of indicator of the brownian motion inside an interval

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, expected-value, stochastic-integrals

Suppose $W_t$ is your usual brownian motion and that you have the following process:

$$ \theta_t = \int_0^t \mathbb{1}_{\alpha \leq W_s \leq \beta} ds $$

How can I calculate the expectation $E[\theta_T]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may apply the Fubini theorem. Its hypotheses are satisfied. So you get:

$$E[\theta_T] = \int_0^T P[W_s \in [\alpha,\beta]] ds = \int_0^T \int_\alpha^\beta \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi s}} \exp(-\frac{x^2}{2s}) ~dx ~ds. $$

Etc.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, we can have a semi-analytical formula of the expected value of $\theta$. 
Thanks to Fubini, we have: $t>0$

\begin{align}
E[\theta_t] &= \int_0^t E[1_{\alpha \leq W_s \leq \beta}]ds \\
&= \int_0^t P(\alpha \leq W_s \leq \beta)ds \\
&= \int_0^t \Phi\left(\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{s}}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{s}}\right)ds
\end{align}
Where $\Phi$ is cumulative distribution function of standard Gaussian variable. By means of multiple integration by parts,
we have 
\begin{equation}
\int_0^t \Phi\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{s}}\right)ds = (2x^2 + t)\Phi\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{t}}\right) + 2x\left(\frac{\sqrt{t}e^{-x^2/t}}{\sqrt{\pi}} - x\right)
\end{equation}